# Is it possible to optimally route browser data: try localhost then local network then internet

Tags: http, routes

Let's say that I'm building a web app that will be required to exchange data with 3 possible entities:

- Another open browser window open on the same machine.
- A browser on a different machine that is still within the same intranet.
- A browser on a machine outside of the intranet.

Is it possible to somehow finagle to HTTP protocol so that the data is optimally routed?

- If the transfer is on the same machine, then the request should never even reach the router.
- If the transfer is in the intranet, then the request should never make it onto the internet at large.
- If the transfer is outside of the intranet - then so be it.

Comment: Do you know how (what technologies/methods) you are going to talk to another browser window on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with HTTP. 
What you want is exactly what properly configured routing does.

You need a combination of a properly configured DNS and a router and communication with local hosts will never pass the router.